# Text field returning a null value

Tags: jtextfield

I am working on a code for school where you would have choose a type of loan and then it would take the amount you owed and tell you how long it will take to pay off the loan. I used some basic JTextFields to allow user input and then used the .getText() to retrieve the information. However when ever i use that field it returns a nullnull in my console. I have been trying to solve this for a while and have changed the code quite a bit, and i am fairly new to coding, so it might be a little hard to follow. I would apreciate if someone could help me out on why it is returning a null?

CODE HERE

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Loan1 extends JFrame  implements ActionListener
 {
String paymentTotal, total;
double a;
double b;
double g;
String Total;
FlowLayout flowLayout = new FlowLayout();
private JButton bl = new JButton("Business Loan");
private JButton pl = new JButton("Personal Loan");
private JButton cl = new JButton("Create a Loan");
private JButton submit = new JButton("Submit");
TextField textField = new TextField(20);


JLabel thing = new JLabel("How long were you looking to payoff the loan?");
JLabel thing2 = new JLabel("you will have to pay " + g + " $ a month");


    public Loan1(){
        setLayout(flowLayout);
        add("Business Loan",bl);
        add("Personal Loan",pl);
        add("Create a Loan",cl);
        bl.addActionListener(this);
        pl.addActionListener(this);
        cl.addActionListener(this);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if (e.getSource() == bl || e.getSource() == pl 
|| e.getSource() ==   cl)

            payment();
        if (e.getSource() == submit) {
            Submit();
        }
        repaint();
        //b = new Double(Total);
        System.out.print(Total);
        System.out.print(paymentTotal);
        add(thing);
        TextField textField = new TextField(20);
        String text = textField.getText();
        add(textField);
        remove(bl);
        remove(cl);
        remove(pl);

        if(text.equals("1")){
            a = 1;
            //g = paymentTotal/a *12
            add(thing2);
        }
        if(text.equals("2")){
            a = 2;
            //g = paymentTotal/a *12
            add(thing2);
        }
        if(text.equals("3")){
            a = 3;
            //g = paymentTotal/a *12
            add(thing2);
        }
        if(text.equals("4")){
            a = 1;
            //g = paymentTotal/a *12
            add(thing2);
        }
        if(text.equals("5")){
            a = 1;
            //g = paymentTotal/a *12
            add(thing2);
        }
        }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Loan1 JBL = new Loan1();
        JBL.setSize(250,250);
        JBL.setVisible(true);
    }


    public void payment() {
        JLabel thing1 = new JLabel("How much money
   were you looking to get a loan for?");
        add(thing1);
        add(textField);
        add(submit);
    }
    public void Submit (){
        String Total = textField.getText();
        paymentTotal = Total;
        System.out.print(Total);
        remove(textField);

    }

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

first: In your method payment(), you have forget:

```
submit.addActionListener(this);
```

and why you did not specify for each button its own actionPerformed ?

Comment: All that does is change the interest rate on it (Witch i haven't added yet) it runs and asks the same question, so i was going to change it with the .getsource because i will change 1 variable, and thanks for the help, now it returns a number then  null, witch i am assuming is because submit only works on our first text field. I will add it to the second part too and see what it does.

Comment: @LukeHedrick okyy